# Save append variable output to json file in datafactory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a variable append activity with the following output:

{
"Name": "xxxxxxx",
"WebId": "xxx"
}, {
"Name": "xxxx",
"WebId": "xxxx"
}, {
"Name": "xxxx",
"WebId": "xxxx"
}, {
"Name": "xxxx",
"WebId": "xxxx"
}, {
"Name": "xxxx",
"WebId": "xxxx"
}, {
"Name": "xxxx",
"WebId": "xxxx"
}, {
"Name": "xxxx",
"WebId": "xxxx"
}

How can I save that output as a json file or better yet as a csv file in a datalake

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert String type to Json type? You can try `@json(variable_name)` to convert.

Comment: no, what I need is to save in a datalake the result of a variable whose output is in json format

Comment: I studied for a while before. Unfortunately, we can't sink a variable into a json file or csv file. But we can sink it into Azure SQL via Stored Procedure activity.

Comment: Or we can via Azure Function, use POST method to send the variable and save it into ADL.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to save output as file directly in Azure Data factory.

As an alternative, you can use  Azure function to create a file and write the output to this file.